# Setting up A and CNAME records for azure shared hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, cname-record, godaddy

I am trying to set up my dns records so that I can point my domain to my azure hosting. Everything is working fine except my www.mydomain.com does not direct to my website on Azure. However mydomain.com does work. I have tried creating a cname record that directs www to the root domain but this is not working.

I'm using godaddy and my records are set up like this:

```
A
Host: @, Points to: *azure ip*

CNAME
Host: www, Points to: mydomain.com
Host: awverify, Points to: awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, had to add www.mydomain.com to azure and had to add the following entries into the dns records.

```
A Host: www, Points to: azure ip 
CNAME Host: awverify.www, Points to: awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net
```

I removed `CNAME Host: www, Points to: mydomain.com`